# Visual Studio Create Solution By Text Replacing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

In our company projects, it is often painful process to set up a new template solution based on company dll's and UI components.

To create new solution, I copy an existing solution "by string replacing old project names to new project name".

For example, .sln and .csproj files are text files. Programmatically I replace string content of such files. And I don't apply replacement, just copy for .dll, .exe, .pdb files.

When I open new .sln file, Visual studio says "Invalid Solution File". I cannot open new solution.

How can I create new solution from an existing one?
(Visual Studio 2012, C#, ASP.NET project)

Comment: since the process is painful, fix it at the source instead: create .props files in which common dlls/ui/... are included, then import those props files in your projects. Added benefit: if one of the dlls changes you won't have to update all project files, just the props file. Also use props files for *all* volatile options. A good project file only contains sources/references it needs. The rest of the config is in common shared files.

Comment: Second fix: instead of copy/pasting projects, write a simple project file generator (pretty easy in C# using classes from Microsoft.Build namespace). It only takes like 20 man-hours or so, but it also means you will never have problems like this again in the future.